# Make a Highscore Screen in App Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

I want to add a Highscore Screen to my Quiz App. I've already created a Highscore Screen with a start value, which contains the score the user has reached in the last round, the category-name and the difficulty.

I split this start value into 2 variables:

The first contains only the score and the other one the category and the difficulty. Now all in all I have 3 categories and 2 difficultys for each of them. Now I want to keep the top 10 Highscores of each category and difficulty. Like this:

```
Category 1 Difficulty 1
Category 1 Difficulty 2
Category 2 Difficulty 1
Category 2 Difficulty 2
Category 3 Difficulty 1
Category 3 Difficulty 2
```

As you can see, I will have 6 different Highscore lists.

Now my question:

How can I save all of the 6 lists in my TinyDB and reload the data again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each of the lists use its own tag for TinyDB
to save one of the lists, use the TinyDB.StoreValue block, to get it again in Screen.Initialize use the TinyDB.GetValue block, see also the [docu](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/basic.html#TinyDB)
 and remember: on first run TinyDB is empty, see [an example here](http://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#canvas) how to handle that.
and: [do the tutorials](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/tutorials.html) to get familiar with the basic concepts of App Inventor.